# Разница в использовании Char vs (PChar or ^Char)

Tags: delphi, указатели

Я начал изучать pointers и не пойму какой от них смысл, когда можно не использовать их в всё тоже работает. В примере использования указателей, отображении каждого символа из строки осуществляется с помощью Pchar или ^char, хотя это же можно сделать с помощью Char.

PChar или ^Char:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var myString  : string;
    myCharPtr : PChar; //Или ^Char
    i : Integer;
begin
   myString  := 'Hello World';
   i:=1;
   myCharPtr := Addr(myString[i]);
   while i <= Length(myString) do
   begin
     ShowMessage(myCharPtr^);
     Inc(i);
     Inc(myCharPtr);
   end;
end;
```

Char:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var myString  : string;
    myChar : Char;
    i : Integer;
begin
    myString  := 'Hello World';
    for I := 1 to Length(myString) do
    begin
      MyChar:=mystring[i];
      ShowMessage(myChar);
    end;
end;
```

Работают одинаково на мой взгляд. Так какой смысл использовать PChar (^Char)?

P.s. есть разница между PChar и ^Char?

Comment: Оба примера неоправданно усложнены. Достаточно простого `for i := 1 to Length(myString) do ShowMessage(myString[i]);`. Есть гораздо более наглядные примеры того, когда указатели действительно приносят пользу.

Comment: @Kromster Согласен, но тут вопрос не в пользу оптимально короткого решения для цикла, а в использовании или же неиспользовании указателей.

Comment: А вы примеры то запускали? А то ... второй выводит HIJKL... вместо Hello

Comment: @Kromster Не учёл, согласен, исправил.

Comment: То есть у вас высосаный из пальца пример? И нам надо объяснить ... что? ) *картинка про троллейбус из буханки*

Comment: Пример именно в использовании Char против PChar (^Char)... результат вывода не должен иметь разницу. По тому же принципу я не пойму, почему **for i :=1 to Length(myString) do
   begin
     myCharPtr := Addr(myString[i]);
     ShowMessage(myCharPtr^);
     //Inc(myCharPtr);
   end;** что с **Inc(myCharPtr);**, что без него выдает одинаковый результат.

Comment: Очевидно же: присваиваем адрес нужного символа `myCharPtr := Addr(myString[i]);` перед ShowMessage, поэтому всегда будет выводиться i-тый символ строки myString. Что после ShowMessage с myCharPtr происходит - абсолютно не имеет значения, потому что в следующей итерации цикла перед выводом сообщения на экран снова будет выполнено `myCharPtr := Addr(myString[i]);`

Answer (score 3):

Переменная типа `Char` - содержит непосредственно символ (его значение). Операции с ним влияют только на него.

Переменная типа `^Char` - содержит указатель на символ. Операции с указателем влияют только на указатель. Операции с разыменованым указателем - влияют на то на что он указывает. Для чего вообще нужны указатели - отдельная тема, но вкратце - чтобы работать с одним набором данных в нескольких местах.

Переменная типа `PChar` - во многом идентична `^Char` (`PChar = ^Char`). Однако, например, они не взаимоприсваеваемы.

Comment: Последнее утверждение не совсем корректно: Delphi придерживается жёсткой типизации. Поэтому вы не сможете присвоить переменной a (PChar) значение b (^Char).

Comment: @ViktorTomilov ценное уточнение, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Давайте посмотрим на определение PChar в Delphi:

```
PChar = ^WideChar (в некоторых случаях PChar = ^Char, т.е. ANSIChar)
```

С точки зрения того, чтобы рассматривать PChar только как указатель на тип Char, вы правы: смысла не очень много. Кстати, с этой же точки зрения нет почти никакой разницы между PChar и ^Char.

Однако, PChar используется также как указатель на строку, заканчивающуюся символом #0 (null-terminated string, строка, используемая в большинстве системных вызовов, где требуется строковая переменная). И вот в этом случае утверждать о бессмысленности PChar как-то неправильно :)

Comment: Не совсем понял ваш второй параграф. А в первом бессмыслица, PChar разве равен ^WideChar? А на AnsiChar есть свой PAnsiChar или же ^AnsiChar. Не так ли?

Comment: @SovereignSun  По второму параграфу: откройте описание любой системной функции на MSDN, требующей строку, увидите PChar, то есть указатель на литеру используется как указатель на строку. По-второму: да, обычно по умолчанию PChar = PWideChar = ^WideChar, - но можно менять директивами компилятора (т.е. можно указать, что PChar=^ANSIChar и т.п)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov По-моему, директивами тип `PChar` не поменяешь и на какой именно тип (AnsiChar или WideChar) от указывает, зависит от версии компилятора. Его можно попытаться переопределить в своём юните, но это будет игра с огнём.

Comment: @zed Никто не мешает залезть в system,pas и поменять (безопаснее создать alias и менять уже в нём), да и в своем проекте переопределить никто не помешает. Просто, на каждом шаге нужно понимать, зачем нам это нужно. А часто подобное нужно для ускорения/минимизации потребления памяти, к примеру.

Answer (score 0):

В первом варианте (где PChar) у тебя значение в myCharPtr будет указывать на участок памяти, выделенный под i-тый символ переменной myString. Т.е. меняешь данные по адресу myCharPtr  - меняется значение myString[i] (и наоборот). Во втором варианте ты копируешь символ из одного участка памяти (mystring[i]) в совершенно другой участок памяти (выделенный под переменную MyChar). Соответственно, когда меняешь одно из этих значений - второе не меняется.

Comment: Это я так полагаю имеет смысл только тогда, когда нужно использовать один участок памяти и видоизменять его. Если же нет смысла экономить на памяти и видоизменять строку, то первый вариант смысла не имеет, так?

Comment: Да в принципе - да, не имеет абсолютно. Просто в некоторых языках типа C++ по умолчанию принято работать с указателями, даже когда в этом нет особого смысла :)

Comment: Меня вот мучает вопрос, неужели необходимо со всеми переменными и типами работать с указателями, судя по некоторым статьям, работа с другими переменными или же подтипами без указателей с точки зрения правильного приложения неправильна. То есть тот же PChar необходим, а Char это избыток и неправильно написанный код приводящий к неправильной оптимизации приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Изучать указатели лучше на тех примерах, для которых они предназначены. Например, реализуя такие типы данных, как *связный список* или *двоичное дерево*.

Работать с символами строки посредством указателей — не в парадигме Pascal и без указателей код получится гораздо проще. А вот связный список реализовать без указателей не получится в принципе. Сделайте и поймёте, какой в них смысл.

Comment: А можно пример такого задания? и информацию о таких задачах?

Comment: @SovereignSun В интернете есть замечательная поисковая машина https://google.ru, которая позволяет быстро находить интересующую информацию. Например, прочитав в моём посте словосочетание *связный список*, которое я выделил курсивом, мы можете зайти в гугол и ввести его там. Гугол покажет вам результаты поиска, и первым будет ссылка на статью в википедии на русском языке. Вот эта ссылка: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Связный_список. Перейдя по ссылке, вы ознакомитесь с примером и информацией.